# Paragraph reformatting while using smartindent in Vim

Tags: vim, formatting, indentation

In Vim 7.4, how can I reformat paragraphs the following way with the `gq}` command while using the `set smartindent` option (I need that option)?

- Before reformatting:

  > ```
  > 1     Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem
  >   accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa,
  >   quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae
  >   dicta sunt, explicabo.
  > 2     Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas
  >   sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni
  >   dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro
  >   quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit, amet,
  >   consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi
  >   tempora incidunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat
  >   voluptatem.
  > ```
- After reformatting (*what I want*) — notice the line numbers:

  > ```
  >  1     Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem
  >  2 accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa,
  >  3 quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae
  >  4 dicta sunt, explicabo.
  >  5     Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas
  >  6 sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni
  >  7 dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro
  >  8 quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit, amet,
  >  9 consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi
  > 10 tempora incidunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat
  > 11 voluptatem.
  > ```

With `set formatoptions=qw`, I get the desired result (the block ‘After reformatting’). But if I add the option `set smartindent`, every line of the paragraph becomes indented (*what I get*):

> ```
>  1     Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit
>  2     voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem
>  3     aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi
>  4     architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo.
>  5     Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut 
>  6     odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui 
>  7     ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, 
>  8     qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit, amet, consectetur, adipisci 
>  9     velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt, ut 
> 10     labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.
> ```

Comment: If you had two lines in your paragraph (which you don't) you could have add `set fo+=2` to get the desired effect. The problem is you only have 1 line in your paragraph and vim doesn't know what the indentation should look like. So it just keeps the indentation of the first line for all of them. I don't think vim is aware of word wrap on the screen.

Comment: @FDinoff: No, I do precisely have two lines in my example (look at the line numbers in the block _Before reformatting_). But anyway the option `set formatoptions+=2` tells Vim to use the indentation of the second line (instead of the one of the first line) for the following lines (third line, fourth line, etc.) and that is not what I want either. I want to **keep** the indentations of **each** line of the paragraph.

Comment: idk if this is helpful, but have you looked into the `fmt` command instead?

Comment: @user2326961 but each paragraph only has one line. (Maybe I'm just misunderstanding what you are trying to do.)

Comment: smartindent is discouraged. You should just be using autoindent.

Comment: @acushner: Yes but I want to use the `gq` command.

Comment: @FDinoff: I think we do not have the same definition of a paragraph. For me and Vim, paragraphs are made of successive lines, and are separated by at least **one blank line**. My example holds two successive lines so it is one paragraph made of two lines.

Comment: @Dhruva Sagar: Why is `smartindent` discouraged? But anyway using `autoindent` does not work either, each line is still indented.

Comment: So what is the output you are looking for?

Comment: @FDinoff: The second block. I get the third one instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn off `smartindent`. Don't replace it with `autoindent`. Both of these options will use the indent of the 1st line for any following lines in your simple (prose) case. `smartindent` is actually pretty bad anyway and mostly discouraged; it has been replaced with `cindent` and expression-based indenting (via `indentexpr`). Mostly you can actually turn on filetype-specific indent rules, but I don't know of any that exist for prose.

Comment: Okay. But `cindent` does not solve my problem either since it also uses the indentation of the first line for any following _visual_ lines when I use `gq}`. This `gq` command shouldn't indent _visual_ lines according to if `cindent` (or `autoindent` or `smartindent`) is set or not. It should **never** do it.

Comment: gq will ALWAYS apply the new indent. The solution in your case is don't use ANY automatic indenting, or find one for writing prose. No matter what, if you're breaking one line into multiple, gq is going to apply some indent rule.

Comment: Also I wasn't saying cindent would solve your problem. cindent is meant for code. You are writing prose. smartindent is also meant for code. So you should not be using it right now either.

Answer (score 1):

If you want automatic indentation in prose, I would suggest using `'autoindent'` rather than `'smartindent'` (which is not actually very smart). Combine that with a `2` in your `'formatoptions'` setting, and you can reformat existing multiline paragraphs and the indent will *remain* correct on the 2nd line and higher.

But I know of no way to configure Vim so that it will indent the first line and not the other lines. You need to set the indent of either the first or second line manually, then Vim can format the rest of the lines properly.